# Sort MySQL data using a selection menu

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a selection menu that has an option on how will the data from my database will be sorted.  I'm stuck on how will I sort it according to date and exam.

This is my code so far:

```
echo "<form action=results.php method=post>";
echo "Sort By: <select name=q><option value= name=></option><option value=date name=date>Date</option><option value=exam name=exam>Exam</option></select>";
echo "</form>";

if()
$q = $_GET['q'];

echo "<table border=1 align=center><tr class=style2><td>Date <td>Student Name <td> Subject <td> Score";

$sortQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mst_adminresult m
JOIN mst_test t ON t.test_id = m.test_id
JOIN mst_subject s ON s.sub_id = t.sub_id order by'".$q."'" ,$cn) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($sortQuery))
{
    echo "<tr class=style8><td>$row[5]<td>$row[1] <td align=center> $row[4] <td align=center> $row[3]/20";   
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: The fields in the ORDER BY clause should be wrapped in backticks instead of single quotes, specially since you're using the reserved word `date`. But tbh, if that's the way you code, you have much bigger problems than just a couple of missing backticks. I hope it's just your sample code ... you don't even check if `$_GET['q']` is set or not

Comment: i know I have to `isset()` it but that's the problem I'm having... i don't know the proper way to do it. I'm stuck with `if(isset($_GET['q']) == "examdate")` it should be, if the value is equals to examdate, it will sort by date, @Kirito

Comment: You can't evaluate `if(isset($_GET['q']) == "examdate")`, well, you can, but you're getting unexpected results. `isset` only returns true or false, so use: `if (isset($_GET['q'])) { $q = $_GET['q']; } else { $q = "date"; }` which means that `date` will be the default value in case `$_GET['q']` is not set, or you can change it to `$q = "exam";`, its up to you.

Comment: Many, many years ago, the PHP mysql_ API was found to be insecure. So we stopped using it. Come. Join us.

Answer (score 1):

After "order by" must have a space !

Sample:

```
... ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC ...
```

Comment: i know I have to `isset()` it but that's the problem I'm having... i don't know the proper way to do it. I'm stuck with `if(isset($_GET['q']) == "examdate")` it should be, if the value is equals to examdate, it will sort by date

Answer (score 0):

Here's your revised code, it was giving me anxiety to see it:

```
echo '<form action="results.php" method="post">';
echo 'Sort By: <select name="q"><option value=""></option><option value="date">Date</option><option value="exam">Exam</option></select>';
echo '</form>';

if(isset($_GET['q']) {
  $q = $_GET['q'];
} else {
  $q = 'date';
}

echo '<table border="1" align="center"><tr class="style2"><td>Date</td><td>Student Name</td><td>Subject</td><td>Score</td></tr>';

$sortQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mst_adminresult 
JOIN mst_test t ON t.test_id = m.test_id
JOIN mst_subject s ON s.sub_id = t.sub_id order by `".$q."`" ,$cn) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($sortQuery))
{
  echo '<tr class="style8"><td>$row[5]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td align=center>$row[4]</td><td align=center>$row[3]/20</td></tr>';   
}
echo '</table>';
```

Some observations:

- Options inside selects do not need a name
- Many of your s didn't have a closing
- Your s had no closing
- Use single quotes to wrap text that uses a lot of double quotes or escape the double quotes: `'this "text"'` or `"this \"text\""`

I hope it helps.